# How do I see the list of changed files for a single commit, in Git?

Tags: git

When I say git status I get a list of changed files. I'd like to get a list of changed files for a commit. Is there a way to use git show or some other command to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, simply pass the `--stat` flag:

```
git show --stat 1268afe676e
```

For commits, `git show` takes the same formatting arguments as `git diff-tree`, so see [the latter's documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html) for other formatting options.

Comment: `git show --stat [COMMIT, ...] >> file.md !To boss! `

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `git log --stat` or `git log --stat COMMIT`

Comment: The asker is looking for a list files for a _single_ commit.

Comment: Apologies. See bdonlan's answer.

Comment: You can edit or update your answer if you want to improve it.

Comment: @charles-bailey Should I edit or update the answer in a case like this, when another answer is correct?